# How do you write to a local json file in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to update a json file within my React Native app. Is it possible to write  to a json file in React Native?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`write-json`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/write-json-file#readme) for this

```
import {writeJsonFile} from 'write-json-file';

await writeJsonFile('foo.json', {foo: true});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I installed the package but i get the following error after trying to write a file:

Unable to resolve module node:path from C:\Users\aldeg\Documents\Capstone\practice_react_native\node_modules\write-json-file\index.js: node:path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\write-json-file\node_modules
  node_modules